# Are there any different between ’//‘ and ’/‘ with int() operation in python?

Tags: python

Here is a sample

```
a = 5 //2 
b = int(5/2)
```

We all know that a = b = 2.
My question is

```
can a // b  allways equal int(a/b) ?
```

I can't find a wrong example...so far

Comment: Relevant links for self-learning: [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), and [`//` (floor division)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) (name already gives a hint)

Comment: `a//b` gives a quotient: the number you would get if you long-divided those numbers and threw away the remainder. `int(a/b)` just rounds a completely divided `a/b` number off toward zero. Like the answer below said, negative numbers are the curious case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: `//` always rounds down, whereas `int(...)` rounds towards zero, so they can have different results for negative numbers.

```py
>>> -1 // 2
-1
>>> int(-1 / 2)
0
```

Comment: Just for negative numbers? I'm getting different results for `1 // 0.1` and `int(1/0.1)` as well.

Comment: @WanderNauta Well, you can also get different results by writing a class with different implementations of `__truediv__` and `__floordiv__`; I think the question is implicitly about integers, but I didn't say it is only for negative numbers. The question just asked for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference when you start trying it with negative numbers

```
>>> -3.5//2
-2.0
>>> int(-3.5/2)
-1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above, take the following case :

```
a = 53.76
b = 7.37
```

The output of `a // b` operation is a real number (`7.0`) while the output of `int(a/b)` will always be an integer (`7`).

Small difference ...